# camera calibration opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

Hi i am doing a project to do an image 3d reconstruction. I am the phase of calibrating the camera, which is taking a long time to do. But when i compile the code and display the checkerboard in front of the camera it goes straight to exception error unhandled.

When picture not in frame, no error as soon as it gets in the frame, unhandled error occurs i don't know why.

I have asked a lot of people, no body can seem to help.

here is my code

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numBoards = 0;
    int numCornersHor;
    int numCornersVer;

    printf("Enter number of corners along width: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCornersHor);

    printf("Enter number of corners along height: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCornersVer);

    printf("Enter number of boards: ");
    scanf("%d", &numBoards);

    int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
    Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);
    VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(0);

    vector<vector<Point3d>> object_points;
    vector<vector<Point2d>> image_points;

    vector<Point2d> corners;
    int successes=0;

    Mat image;
    Mat gray_image;
    capture >> image;

    vector<Point3d> obj;
    for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
        obj.push_back(Point3d(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));

    while(successes<numBoards)
    {
        cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        if(found)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
        }

        imshow("win1", image);
        imshow("win2", gray_image);

        capture >> image;

        int key = waitKey(1);

        if(key==27)
            return 0;

        if(key==' ' && found!=0)
        {
            image_points.push_back(corners);
            object_points.push_back(obj);
            printf("Snap stored!\n");

            successes++;

            if(successes>=numBoards)
                break;
        }
    }

    Mat intrinsic = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    Mat distCoeffs;
    vector<Mat> rvecs;
    vector<Mat> tvecs;

    intrinsic.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
    intrinsic.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;

    calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    Mat imageUndistorted;
    while(1)
    {
        capture >> image;
        undistort(image, imageUndistorted, intrinsic, distCoeffs);

        imshow("win1", image);
        imshow("win2", imageUndistorted);

        waitKey(1);
    }

    capture.release();

    return 0;
}
```

the error i get on the console is

OpenCV ERROR: Assertion failed (ncorners >=0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F) in unknown function file , file .....\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\cornersubpix.cpp, line 257.

and the error dialog says

Unhandled exception at 0x769afc16 in basiccalibration.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0021f51c..

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The opencv package has a sample code within it to calibrate cameras, are you using that?

Comment: no, i want to write my own code. i tried that but it had too many errors such as undefined functions.

Comment: I am trying to run the same code than you. Actually my code was a bit different, but I modified it to get some thing close to you and try solve my problem here. Some questions:
In your final version, are you really using numCornersHor twice? Why are you not using numCornersVer as second parameter?
And did you define both as float when you declared them? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Point2f and Point3f instead of Point2d and Point3d. Read the assertion text please. It demands a CV_32F depth structure.

Comment: im new to this so i don't understand the error, so i don't what you mean by demands a CV_32F depth structure. When i do use point 2f and 3f it says warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data for line 'obj.push_back(Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));' it shows this twice so building fails that's why i changed it to point3d and point2d.

Comment: so i get error. any suggestions, thanks for the reply. hope i can get this sorted out.

Comment: You know, the warning is there because You are assigning an integer to place where a float is `(j/numCornersHor,j%cornersHor)`. About depths, it is addressed in [documentation of `cv::Mat.depth()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth)

Comment: so i should change the numcornerver and hor to float.

Comment: don't the assertion doesn't come anymore after i converted them to float, but the code in the assertion error is not in my code and what matrix does it require the depth to be CV_32F as the corners is a vector in my program. regarding the int to float error i tried converting it to float but more error just popped up. how do i make it a float

Comment: ok, i decided to use float(j/numcornershor) for both the int argument and that seemed to have solved, was this a good way to solve it or is it inefficient in some way. thanks for you help